# MySQL calculated expression from other fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields

EventDay
EventMonth
EventYear

and
clcEventDate

I wish for clcEventDate to be populated automatically using this

EventDay/EventMonth/EventYear

I tried writing the following as the Default/Expression of clcEventDate:
EventDay + "/" + EventMonth + "/" + EventYear

But the field just shows up blank

What is the correct way to do what I am trying to accomplish

***UPDATE****

So the way to go about it with MySQL is using a Before Insert trigger

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER clcEventDate_FilesMain
BEFORE INSERT ON FilesMain
FOR EACH  ROW 
BEGIN 
     SET NEW.clcEventDate = CONCAT(NEW.EventDay,'/', NEW.EventMonth,'/',NEW.EventYear);
END;
#
DELIMITER ;
```

So now I have a different question:
if for example the value of EventMonth is 8 but when concating the string I wish the value to be double digits so 8 become 08 but 10 stays 10. . . how can this be done so the end result will be for example 02/08/2020 although value of EventDay is 2 and EventMonth is 8

Thank you

Comment: wouldn't it be better to create a view with the calculated field and just select from the view?

Comment: + is numeric operator in MySQL useCONCAT

Comment: It probably would but data is migrated from tsql and that is how it is built there. Instructions were to keep data EXACTLY like in TSQL

Comment: You cannot tsql and MySQL are not the same I guess the instruction was to make the outcome the same and that could result in different code

Comment: @P.Salmon As close as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What mysql version are you on? You could use [Generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) instead of triggers:

```
ALTER TABLE FilesMain ADD COLUMN clcEventDate VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(LPAD(NEW.EventDay, 2, "0"),'/', LPAD(NEW.EventMonth, 2, "0"),'/',NEW.EventYear)) STORED;
```

If you do stick with triggers, remember to also have a BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Comment: version 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1